# CPU/PC Freezing (Temperature?)

Tags: memory, cpu, freeze

I have a pc (Windows 10) that randomly freezes throughout the day (Every 20-40 minutes, both while and while not playing games). I have run memory checks and disk checks, and so I wanted to see if it was my temps, so I downloaded software. Here's my specs then the screenshot.
*MSI 970 Gaming Motherboard
*EVGA 16GB DDR3
*FX-8350 8-Core
*GTX 1060 3GB ASUS
(None are overclocked)
Here's the sc: 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLSN2.png)

-Are my temps too hot? (do I need better cooling?)
-Do I need to replace something?
-Any other tips for solving this issue?
(It's also nearing summer and it's getting hot outside, so that's also a factor)
Thanks!

Comment: What was the CPU load when you measured the temps? A desktop PC should run cooler than that usually when it is idle. You should see what the temps do when you put a load on it. A good burn in tester is Aida64. Use it as a trial and run the burn in test. It will graph the load and temps. If the temps jump up really fast or drop really fast or go unusually high, on and off a load, then there might be a problem with the cooling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does seem a bit warm: specs list [maximum operating temperature as 61°C](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bulldozer/AMD-FX-Series%20FX-8350.html), and your image shows ~73°C. You could try cleaning the CPU fan and aiming a desk fan at the nearest vent holes to see if the slowdown is less of an issue. If so, an aftermarket heat-sink might help... or not.

That said, look also to other processes stealing CPU, e.g. malware or coin miner in background.